# How to sum over criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a table of First/Last names and Salaries.I want to compute, for every last name, the sum of the salaries of people with that name.

I know how to do that for each name individually using SUMIF, but I was wondering if there is a quick function to produce a table of Last names and Salary sums?

Comment: Pivot table?...

Comment: A very good read https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions01.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using a pivot table.

1. On the insert tab, select pivot table
2. Use your existing table as the data
3. In the fields select the `Last Name` and `Salary` columns

Answer (score 0):

Let's support you have the salary sheet in sheet1 as below,

[image]

copy column last name value to sheet2.column A, remove duplicate, add a new column as Salary Sum in column B, input a formula as =SUMIF(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C) and drop down to all rows, then you can got a salary sum table as below,

[image]

of course, if the first name/last name is dynamic and unexpected, it would doesn't work. you can drop a button and bind a VBA code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) **ARRAY FORMULA:  CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$7),0)),"")
```

For summing up the corresponding values just use

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,D2)
```

[image]